ROS2 Jazzy Installation Question (Raspberry Pi 4B)
I have been struggling with getting ROS2 to work properly on Raspberry Pi 4B. As a newcomer to this area, I have a fundamental question - given that I have setup my Raspberry Pi 4B with the Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble) Operating System, which of the following installation methods should I be choosing to install ROS2:
(1) Ubuntu (Debian)
(2) Alternatives: Ubuntu (source)
(3) Alternatives: Ubuntu (binary)

The recommended approach would be: Ubuntu (Debian)
This method involves using pre-built binary packages provided by the ROS2 community. It is the easiest and most straightforward method, especially for someone just starting out.
Let me know if you run into issues while installing it using Debian.

Hi, I attempted Ubuntu (Debian) as you recommended. Thus far, there has been no issues. Thank you so much for letting me know! NOTE: my previous attempts using Ubuntu (source) eventually resulted in the ROS2 environment variables disappearing upon either opening a new shell/rebooting my system.

Happy to help. Common etiquette- once you are satisfied with an answer, do upvote it (helps identifying the best answer when there are multiple) and mark the question as answered which indicates that the question is already answered and also helps the author.
-Cheers
